# External Western Digital HDD not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've an external Western Digital HDD that suddenly decided to make problems.

I have 3 computers and this is the behavior:

- Laptop WIN10 - formatted to exFAT and it works.
- PC WIN10 - is detected by Device Manager, but when trying to format
  I get "Data Error (cyclic redundancy check)".
- PC WIN7 - not detected at all in Device Manager.

Hope you guys can help me figure out what is the problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting using the same cable each time? Try another cable.

Comment: @Tetsujin, i've tried another cable and it's seem to be the same

Comment: OK. Next test. Mount it internally in one of the desktops & use something like [CrystalDisk](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) to check the smart status [you cannot do that over USB, it must be mounted internally.]

Comment: @Tetsujin, I dont have any sata connector on it, only the usb3 type b(the regular connector).

Comment: You'll have to strip it from its case; that will help identify whether it's the drive or the controller in the case.

Comment: i've strip it from the case, there is a picture: https://i.imgur.com/lYBPhqD.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106682/discussion-between-itzikb-and-tetsujin).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error of "Data Error (cyclic redundancy check)" on one computer,
the disk is not detected at all on another, but works on a third one.

Quoting from Wikipedia
[Cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check):

> A cyclic redundancy check (CRC) is an error-detecting code commonly used in digital networks and storage devices to detect accidental changes to raw data. Blocks of data entering these systems get a short check value attached, based on the remainder of a polynomial division of their contents. On retrieval, the calculation is repeated and, in the event the check values do not match, corrective action can be taken against data corruption. CRCs can be used for error correction.

This means that a block of data on the disk is bad. From the problems you are
getting, this block seems to be at the header of the disk.

Since the disk works on the Windows 10 laptop, try to use it to recover the disk.
The following steps assume that the disk is attached to this laptop.

**Analyze disk status**

Retrieve and add to your post the SMART information of the disk, so we can
evaluate its condition.

Several tools can retrieve this information, for example
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
(click on "Storage").

**Fix bad sectors**

Run a Command Prompt (cmd) as Administrator, and enter the following command:

```
chkdsk Z: /F /X /R           (replace "Z" by the drive letter of the external disk)
```

This command may take some time to complete. If it succeeds proceed to the
next step.
If it fails, repeat again, and if it fails again then the disk is unrecoverable.

**Deep format**

- Start Disk Management, right-click the disk and select *Format*
- In "Value label" enter a label
- In "File system" select NTFS
- In "Allocation unit size" select "Default"
- Do NOT check "Perform a quick format"
- Press OK twice and wait for it to finish (may take some time on a large disk).

**Conclusion**

If all the steps above have succeeded, the disk should now be usable on all
your computers.

But if all the steps fail to make the disk detectable on all the computers,
and especially the deep format step, then the disk is unrecoverable.
You may still continue using it on the computer on which it works,
but don't rely on it not to totally fail in the future.

Comment: @itzikb: You need to decide about your bounty before it expires.

Answer (score 0):

If the drive does not work consistently on all systems (trying different cables and connectors to rule out issues not regarding the disk itself), the drive is probably corrupted - i.e. it sustained a damage in some sectors so the data cannot be propetly managed for read/write opeartions, hence the CRC errors, that means that the digest of data being read/written does not match the actual data.

You can check the drive health status from embedded SMART data, using an external SMART utilities or from system's tools.

In example both in W7 and W10 you can use Powershell, a script based on Get-CinInstance like this exampe will give pretty detailed information:

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_diskdrive | Select-Object Status, DeviceID, MediaType, InterfaceType, Model, Size, LastErrorCode, ErrorDescription, ErrorCleared, NeedsCleaning

If you prefer legacy comd scripting, you can use

wmic diskdrive get status

If SMART data poits out the system is seriously damaged, you should not trust it and consider immediate replacement - disk internals routines can mark bad sectors and avoid them, but if there is some mechanical or logical faults the damaged area can extend beyond the point the disk can handle it, and the drive may become suddenly unusable.

If the situation is not critical and you want to try to restore the disk you can try system's built in checkdisk and format tools (disable fast format to perform a full format), but even better would be find low level model-specific diagnostic tools from Western Digital support site.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options (as you have given no more details)
 You bought it as a WD ELEMENTS PORTABLE in your country than welcome to the WD policy that some drives start to misbehave after warranty is over - in this case you could try for a grace exchange/repair solution 
Details for your drive from the WD database below:

```
WX11E77ERCAC    OUT OF WARRANTY WDBUZG0010BBK-WESN  WD ELEMENTS PORTABLE 1TB BLACK WORLDWIDE    14-Dec-2019
```

Sometimes a diagnosic/repair or a firmware upgrade solves the problem - if there is one you'll [find it here](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/263#WD_downloads)

Or option two 
you just (last 6 month) bought the drive from an internet dealer or a "cheap" business - the label not for resale and serial also indicates that - than you might have a - very simple problem its a refurbished (fake) drive.
It came with exFat or the formatting will only work with exFat on certain PCs (mostly Win10) as a test you can try to fill the disk up to 1TB on the PC it works. Then try to read/verify those files it will fail at some point. If you read-out the firmware via tools you will see its not fitting to the label. I use such "scrap" drives for storing media files I don't really need to keep or as torrent/streaming devices. 
You have just to format them with a tool that locks all bad clusters (usually from 1TB you get around 500GB to use). The reason that some PC find the drive others not is the (chinese) OEM firmware (probably not offical WD) so depending on what driver/usb port combinitation you have it works or not.
Steps to take:

- Throw it back to the dealer and get your money back
- Use it as a media/streaming/recording device with reduced storage capacity
- use it as a door stopper

And NO you can not flash a working firmware to it as we do not know the HW geometry (also the chinese did not know ;-) they just did a wild guess)
I hope for you its option one - than writing mails and compaining might help - Good luck